# Multi-Dimensional Arrays in C: are they jagged?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays, ansi-c

A simple question about the C programming language (ANSI-C):

Are the multi-dimensional arrays in C jagged?

I mean - are we talking about "array of arrays" (one array of pointers to other addresses in the memory) , or this is just "long one-dimensional array" (which is stored sequentially in the memory)?

What that bothers me is that I'm kinda sure that:

`matrix[i][j]` is equivalent to `* (  *  (matrix + i) + j)`

Comment: It is based on how you are going to allocate memory.

Comment: @KarthikSurianarayanan Of course. I'm talking about the regular declration of multi-dimensional-arrays, like: int matrix[3][4];

Comment: @programmer get your self a copy of the C99 standard. its pretty useful, read page 70.

Comment: @tesseract But I'm talking about ANSI-C (and I have the book The C Programming Language 2nd edition).

Answer (score 13):

A multidimensional array in C is contiguous. The following:

```
int m[4][5];
```

consists of 4 `int[5]`s laid out next to each other in memory.

An array of pointers:

```
int *m[4];
```

is jagged. Each pointer can point to (the first element of) a separate array of a different length.

`m[i][j]` is equivalent to `*(*(m+i)+j)`. See the [C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), section 6.5.2.1:

> The deﬁnition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2)))

Thus, `m[i][j]` is equivalent to `(*(m+i))[j]`, which is equivalent to `*(*(m+i)+j)`.

This equivalence exists because in most contexts, expressions of array type decay to pointers to their first element (C11 standard, 6.3.2.1). `m[i][j]` is interpreted as the following:

- `m` is an array of arrays, so it decays to a pointer to `m[0]`, the first subarray.
- `m+i` is a pointer to the `i`th subarray of `m`.
- `m[i]` is equivalent to `*(m+i)`, dereferencing a pointer to the `i`th subarray of `m`. Since this is an expression of array type, it decays to a pointer to `m[i][0]`.
- `m[i][j]` is equivalent to `*(*(m+i)+j)`, dereferencing a pointer to the `j`th element of the `i`th subarray of `m`.

Note that pointers to arrays are different from pointers to their first element. `m+i` is a pointer to an array; it is not an expression of array type, and it does not decay, whether to a pointer to a pointer or to any other type.

Comment: `m+i` *is* an expression of a pointer-type. The type in this case is `int (*)[N]`, where N is the declare width of the inferior dimension. And a function parameter should be declared as a pointer to such a type accordingly if `m + i` is passed, just as if `m` is passed. (or punt and just declare `int param[][N]`, they're equivalent).

Comment: @WhozCraig: `int (*)[N]` is a pointer to an array of ints, not an array itself.

Comment: Ok, I read that last paragraph a half dozen times, and it finally came out right in my head, sry for the extraneous post, you got it right. It was the "does not decay" (a word I absolutely detest on that note, as does the standard) that threw me. +1 btw

Comment: @WhozCraig: Yeah, I don't think the standard ever uses the term. 6.3.2.1 part 3 says "an expression that has
type ‘‘array of *type*’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to *type*’’", but "decay" is easier to Google.

Comment: I asked the question a long time on on SO where the term came from. The oldest reference anyone could find was to 1987. I just hate the term because it infers a functional action taken at runtime, and no such action exists. When discussing the differences, I often simply say, "pointers are variables that *hold* addresses (and have a separate distinct address of their own); arrays are variables that *are* addresses (and their "value" is said-address when assigned to a pointer =P).

Answer (score 3):

**A consecutive memory area:**

```
int arr[N][M];
```

**A non-consecutive memory area:**

```
int** arr = malloc(N*sizeof(int*));
for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    arr[i] = malloc(M*sizeof(int));
```

You can use `arr` as a 2-dimensional array (e.g., `arr[1][2] = 3`) in both cases. But you can safely apply larger copy operations, such as `memset(arr,0,N*M*sizeof(int))`, only in the first case.

Comment: Am I wrong thinking that matrix[i][j] is equivalent to *(*(matrix + i) + j)?

Comment: Yes. You can use `matrix[i][j]` in both cases, but you can use `*(*(matrix + i) + j)` only in the second case. If you attempt to use it for a statically declared array (`matrix[N][M]`), then you will most likely perform an illegal memory access "in the outer `*`".

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem, isn't that exactly what I said in the comment??? OP asked "Am I wrong". I answered "Yes" and provided an example.

Comment: You can use `*(*matrix+i)+j)` in both cases; it is exactly equivalent to `matrix[i][j]` by the definition of the indexing operator.

Comment: @barakmanos: rofl... just went on the _yes_ and _"the same?"_, and noticed I answered the OP's question in the same way: _"Am I wrong...?"_ > Yes

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem: 1. What does "rofl" mean? 2. I'm having second thoughts on this answer to begin with...

Comment: @Programmer, I apologize for confusing you. Yes, they are equivalent statements. However, as explained in the answer, the memory-maps of a statically-allocated array and a dynamically-allocated array are different.

Comment: @barakmanos: Rolling On the Floor Laughing -> I found it amusing that I misread your answer, whereas I said the same thing. and what is the part of your answer you're not sure about

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem: explained one comment above (and also stated by user2357112 four comments above). It's not within the answer itself, however, just on the comment-thread.

Comment: @barakmanos Thanks, so - if in memory this is just "long one dimensional array", why *(*(matrix + i) + j) works correctly? This is contrasted to the way the array is organized in memory, isn't it?

Comment: Whoops, missed a parenthesis. `*(*(matrix+i)+j)`, not `*(*matrix+i)+j)`.

Comment: @Programmer: That's just pointer arithmetic. If I have a string, say, "foobar", and set a pointer `p1` to point to `f`, and `p2` to `b`, then `*(p1+3)` or even `p1[3]` be the same as `p2[0]` or `*p2`

Comment: @Programmer: The compiler still knows to address the "long one dimensional array" as a 2-dimensional array, because it is explicitly specified in the code. So `*(matrix+i)` is compiled into a pointer to the beginning of the `ith` row in the matrix, and `*(row+j)` is compiled into the value of the `jth` item in the row.

Comment: There's no `new` in C, that's a bit odd.

Comment: @unwind: True, thanks for pointing that out (since the question is tagged under `c`); changed to `malloc`

Comment: @barakmanos So, the array isn't jagged in memory, but in the code I should treat it as if it was jagged (hope you get my intention)?

Comment: @barakmanos You seem to have C++ reflexes going strong. [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169). :)

Comment: @Programmer: not sure what you mean by "jagged". If you mean "non-consecutively allocated", then yes - you can refer to any given element with simple indexing (`matrix[i][j]`), but you cannot perform larger read or write operations (such as `memcpy`, `memset` and `memcmp`), which are based on the assumption that the array occupies a consecutive fragment of memory.

Comment: @unwind: Thanks for the advice (interesting post).

Answer (score 2):

This would depend.

Multidimensional arrays in C are sequentially arranged.

You can create jagged arrays if you want using pointers.

Comment: Thanks, I'll copy what I've written to Klas Lindback too: So, why matrix[i][j] is equivalent to *(*(matrix + i) + j), if we are talking about one dimensional array? This is confusing.

Comment: That's not equivalent @Programmer. That means whatever is at an address pointed by whatever is pointed by `matrix + i` plus `j`. This would assume `matrix+i+j` contain a pointer. Which might give you a sigsegv

Comment: equivalent would be `*(matrix +i + j)`

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't what my output shows. Try to run the following program, please, and look at the output (my output is "wrong"):  #include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, j;
    int matrix[3][2] =
    {
        {1, 2},
        {3, 4},
        {5 , 6}
    };

    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        for (j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
            printf("%d ", *(matrix + i + j));

    getchar();
    return 0;
}

Comment: So I'm probably confused. Isn't it a multi-dimensional-array? And if so, why is it jaggged if I didn't use pointers like you have said?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47004/discussion-between-aniket-and-programmer)

Answer (score 1):

If you declare a multi-dimensional array, you get "long one-dimensional array" (which is stored sequentially in the memory).

If you declare a pointer to pointer (to pointer....) you get arrays of arrays.

This difference is a source of much confusion for beginner C programmers.

Comment: Thanks. So, why matrix[i][j] is equivalent to *(*(matrix + i) + j), if we are talking about one dimensional array? This is confusing.

Comment: @Programmer It is not. It should even give you an error at compile-time. `*(matrix + i + j * dim_1)` would be equivalent to `matrix[i][j]` where *dim_1* is the number of elements for the major component.

Comment: um. no, those aren't even close to the same. Firstly, `*(matrix + i + j * dim_1)` would result in a `int(*)[N]` positioned at `matrix[i+j*dim_1]`, completely different than the OP's expression. Secondly, if this *was* done purposely as a single linear 1-dim, the indexing would be *(ar + i*dim_0 + j) to equate to the correct position of what would be `mat[i][j]` in a 2D declared matrix of `int mat[dim_1][dim_0];` (which is, I think, what you were trying to express).

Comment: @Programmer The elements of matrix[i][j] are stored sequentially, like a one-dimensional array is, but conceptually it is 2-dimensional. `matrix[i][j]` is adjacent to `matrix[i][j+1]` while `matrix[i][j]` is located dim_1 `int`s away from `matrix[i+1][j]`.

Answer (score 0):

An array or arrays, such as `int matrix[A][B]` is not jagged, as each element of `matrix` is an `array of B int`.

You want to know that the outcome of `*(*(matrix+i)+j)` is and compare it to the outcome of `matrix[i][j]`.

Since the type of `matrix` is `array of A array of B int`, then the expression `matrix+i` is a pointer that points to the `i`th `array of B int` of `matrix`, and its type is `int (*)[B]`. Dereferencing this expression results in an `array of B int`. The expression `*(matrix+i)+j)` results in a pointer to the `j`th `int` of that array. Dereferencing that expression results in an `int`. This is equivalent to what the expression `matrix[i][j]` would do.

<sub>An array of pointers, such as `int *matrix[A]`, may be jagged, as each element of `matrix` may point to a different sized allocation.</sub>

Comment: Am I wrong thinking that matrix[i][j] is equivalent to *(*(matrix + i) + j)?

Comment: No, but the type of `matrix` matters in terms of figuring out what the additions actually do.

Comment: If matrix is declerated like this: int matrix[2][3]; Is it wrong to say that matrix[1][2] is like writing *(*(matrix + 1) + 2)?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, that `matrix[i][j]` is equivalent to `*(*(matrix + i) + j)`, since `arr[i]` is equivalent to `*(arr + i)`. However, please keep in mind, that if `arr` is declared as

```
int arr[64];
```

then any reference to `arr` may be implicitly converted to `&arr[0]`, that is a pointer to the first element. Same thing happens with arrays of arrays:

```
int matrix[8][8];
```

Here `matrix` has type `int[8][8]`, which is automatically converted to `int (*)[8]` when you add an integer to it, as in `matrix + i`. Then `*(matrix + i)` has type `int[8]`, which is again converted to `int *` when you add `j`, so `*(matrix + i) + j` has type `int *`, therefore `*(*(matrix + i) + j)` has type `int` as expected.

So the point is, that **arrays are not pointers**, it is just that they can be implicitly casted to a pointer to their first element.

So if you allocate arrays of arrays like above (`int matrix[8][8];`), then then all elements are consecutive in memory.